# When to Use Clicked event or Command Binding?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

```
<Button x:Name="ButtonLogin" 
        StyleId="ButtonLogin"
        Grid.Row="5" 
        BackgroundColor="#F44336" 
        BorderRadius="0" 
        TextColor="White" 
        Text="Login to Meetup"
        Command="{Binding LoginCommand}" />
```

or

```
<Button x:Name="ButtonLogin" 
        StyleId="ButtonLogin"
        Grid.Row="5" 
        BackgroundColor="#F44336" 
        BorderRadius="0" 
        TextColor="White" 
        Text="Login to Meetup"
        Clicked="LogMeIn" />
```

Does the use of one or the other matter specifically when designing a `Xamarin` app?

Which approach should be used?

Comment: What do you mean with "correct"? One is for use with `Xamarin`, the other for `WPF`.

Comment: Both can be used in Xamarin xaml template.

Answer (score 3):

Regardless of whether it is `WPF XAML`, `Silverlight XAML` or `Xamarin XAML`, the choice to use one or the other does not affect the *end* performance of the app for at some point it all gets distilled down to codebehind and ultimately into machine code.

With that said if one uses commanding it can be designed to work within the  `MVVM` paradigm and give direct access to functionality which can be either based on the `View`, `ViewModel` and even the `Model` depending on how it is set up.

Since a command is based on [ICommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand(v=vs.110).aspx) interface, that gives the XAML more flexibility to either allow or disallow operations due to the `CanExecute` functionality which is a big selling point if used.

> Both can be used in Xamarin xaml template[?]

The click event is local to the control and cannot be used in a template. The click event can work with `MVVM` but it should not be called from anywhere outside the `View` that contains it.

---

My advice is to use `Commanding` where re-use particulary amongst `Pages`/`Views` is prevalent and also if there exists a need to either directly or indirectly affect styles and visibility; use it. Otherwise if the operation is just local to the page/control there is no reason not to use code-behind.